# ubuntu : cuda package not found (ubuntu 14.04, cuda 8.0)

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dpkg, cuda, deb

Installing cuda on ubuntu 14.04:

went to : https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

selected the options: linux, x86_64, ubuntu, 14.04 and deb(local)

get the instruction:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb
```

which does not work:

```
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
```

anything I can do on my side or something wrong with nvidia servers ?

So instead, I installed cuda via the software manager after downloading the deb file, but that does not seem to come with the samples, which is a bummer

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting the `No such file or directory` error, you have to change directories using `cd` to the directory where cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb is located before you run the `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb` command.